# Showing the whole flexbox in a single row by reducing the width of all boxes

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Finally, I have a row of boxes like this:

[See the code in action on Codepen](https://codepen.io/pixy-dixy/pen/YzqyREg) . StackOverflow can not show it correctly.

Here is the css I used:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "Heebo-Light";
  src: url(Heebo-Light.ttf) format("truetype");
}

svg {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    overflow: visible;
    pointer-events: none;
}


body {
  background-color: #FDFDFD;
}

.box svg:nth-of-type(1) {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  min-width: 0; 
}

.box svg:nth-of-type(2) {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  min-width: 0; 
}

.subbox-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 3px;

   min-width: 0;
}

.main-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  gap: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  /*overflow: hidden;*/
 /* flex-flow: row wrap;*/
min-width: 0; 


}

.background-rectangle {
  transform: translate(49.3315px, -24.31px);
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  margin-right: 0 !important;
  min-width: 0; 
}

.box-container {

  position: relative;
  transform: translate(-49.3315px);
  top: 0;


   min-width: 0;
}

* { min-width: 0; }
```

When the number of boxes is more than 8, or when you resize the browser the page has not the space to show them all with the fixed widths. Since I want to resize all the elements to fit in any size and width I added `min-width: 0;` to all the elements but it doesn't change anything.

I know we can set the `flex-flow: row wrap;` to show all the boxes on the one page, but I wonder if there is a solution with flexbox to reduce the size of all boxes to show them in one row on the page?

I mean if all widths of all boxes reduce a bit the whole thing coud be seen on a singl row... is this possible using flexbox?

Comment: Have you tried using media queries?

Comment: Oh...no... What should I do?

Comment: changing the width seem to not affecting anything...

Comment: Hi !
Add a width to your class : box-container, I will recommand to do it with js with calcul how many box-container you have and divid 100 / (total box-container)
Then just fix the class : `background-rectangle` & `svg` with `max-width:100%`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are adding some inline widths to your child elements. Although you have assigned `min-width: 0` to the parent, the content is still going to take up space due to the static inline width you've defined on the child elements such as `.box`, `.background-rectangle`, and `svg`. To ensure these elements don't go overboard their parent utilize CSS property `max-width`.

```
.box, .background-rectangle, svg {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

https://codepen.io/emineminems/pen/MWyazdQ

Comment: Ok, your solution is working... But I don't understand how to do this in a logical way...

Comment: one last question: How can we change each box width this way? I don't want to have all same size boxes!

Comment: I've updated my answer @Pixier. If you opt to have different `width` for each boxes, just utilize `max-width` property. Again use a relative measurement - in my example I've used `100%` so that the maximum space it'll take is it's parent's `width`. Although, I strongly suggest to just wrap the content in small devices.

Comment: Ok that worked brilliantly... Please don't leave... I'm going to convert all px units to viewport units and try if your solution work then...

Comment: Well Done... the wired part is I did what you did but my code wasn't functional :)

Answer (score 0):

what I don't understand is, do these codes belong to you ? why can't you assign a specific width value for each box ?

You can use media query, which varies for each dimension separately. Like this:

```
 @media screen and (max-width:550px) {
      .box-container1{
          width: xxxxxxxxxx ;
      }
  }


// Extra small devices (portrait phones, less than 576px)
@media (max-width: 575.98px) { ... }

// Small devices (landscape phones, less than 768px)
@media (max-width: 767.98px) { ... }

// Medium devices (tablets, less than 992px)
@media (max-width: 991.98px) { ... }

// Large devices (desktops, less than 1200px)
@media (max-width: 1199.98px) { ... }
```

Reference : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/overview/

Comment: It's not that easy... There are SVGs inside their container that have their own width ...